# To update a column in a table based on a existing data in a column using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server, kindly help

I have a table:

```
Group   id     DEPT     newadmission 
--------------------------------------
 A      001     CS       Y
 A      002     ECE      
 A      003     MC     
 B      561     CS  
 B      781     IT
 C      789     CS       Y
 C      003     CS
```

If a group has a new admission the entire group should get that value.

If there is no new admission it can be as it is.

How can I achieve that?

Desired output

```
Group   id      DEPT    newadmission 
------------------------------------
 A      001     CS          Y
 A      002     ECE         Y   
 A      003     MC          Y  
 B      561     CS    
 B      781     IT
 C      789     CS          Y
 C      003     CS          Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, max(newadmission) over (partition by group) as new_newadmission
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set newadmission = new_newadmission
    where newadmission is null;
```

This assumes that `newadmission` is either `NULL` or `Y`, although it is easily adapted for other values.

Comment: Can't we do that without CTE expression?                                           For eg:-                                                                                                         
    UPDATE t1   SET  t1.newadmission='Y'                                                                                 FROM Table1 t1                                                                                  
 JOIN Table1 t2                                                                                                      
 ON t1.Group=t2.Group

Comment: @PEL1 . . . A self-join would be much more expensive.  Further, it would be a bit more complicated than what you have expressed.  `cross apply` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can just a common table expression followed by an Update statement to get the desired output.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT [Group] FROM
Table1 WHERE newadmission = 'Y'
)
UPDATE t
SET
t.newadmission = 'Y'
FROM 
Table1 t INNER JOIN CTE ON
t.[Group] = CTE.[Group]
```

Comment: Can't we do that without CTE expression?                                           For eg:-                                                                                                         
    UPDATE t1   SET  t1.newadmission='Y'                                                                                 FROM Table1 t1                                                                                  
 JOIN Table1 t2                                                                                                      
 ON t1.Group=t2.Group